# autocorr.plot in R

Tags: r, coda

I am trying to run the autocorrelation function plot on an MCMC chain in R using the function "autocorr.plot" from the package coda in R, however the output doesn't show the confidence limits. 
[image]

Does anyone know how I can add them?

Comment: Please share your data and code. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The base `acf` function has `ci` and `ci.type` options for the confidence interval.